# Django Rest Framework: getting lists from query_params without request.getlist

Tags: json, django, http, django-rest-framework

We use serializers to to validate the data coming into our non-model based service methods. This works great for POSTs as JSON of course but also for GETs generally if the content in the query_params is not complex (not lists or nested). However if I have something like this:

```
class RequestSerializer(Serializer):
   objects = ListField(child=PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Foo.objects.all()), allow_empty=False)
   choice = ChoiceField(choices=my_choices)
```

and on the client I just use a GET like so:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: '...',
   data={
      "objects":[1,2,3],
      "choice":"mychoice"
      ...
```

this works if I use POST instead of GET and set the contentType to "application/json" but this is not condoned by the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.3). It would be nice to be able to handle the simple list use case without doing something like:

```
request_serializer = RequestSerializer(data={"objects" :request.query_params.getlist("objects[]")})
```

Is there some obvious serializer trick I am missing that tells the serializer how to fetch a list(objects=x&objects=y&objects=z) without manually calling *request.getlist*? What is everyone else doing for this, it seems like a common use case?

EDIT:
I did find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083467/django-drf-listfield-to-deserialize-list-of-ids-in-gets-queryparams) earlier but the accepted answer is using *request.getlist* which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use the jQuery [ajaxSettings](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/#jQuery-param-obj-traditional)

```
$.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```

if you are using jQuery in your templates and from what I am reading it should be probably used for the entire project using Django because it does not seem to suffer from the same limitations as other languages.

> As of jQuery 1.4, the $.param() method serializes deep objects
>   recursively to accommodate modern scripting languages and frameworks
>   such as PHP and Ruby on Rails.

Leaving this false causes the variable to come through as "objects[]" and the code that would handle HTML lists in [ListField](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py) never gets invoked because the param has been replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what your question is but seems you should use the `many` argument for the field:

```
class RequestSerializer(Serializer):
    objects = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Foo.objects.all(), allow_empty=False, many=True)
    choice = ChoiceField(choices=my_choices)
```

Comment: Yes, we use **many** in other places. The ListSerializer works as well. The question is about getting a list from query_params (not request.data).