# How to get the multiple value from request for Django-restful-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to get the multiple value from `request`

```
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
def getParamAjax(request):
    print("{0}".format(request.query_params.get('genre')))
```

`localhost/api/genre=test`

it shows `test`, ....ok

`localhost/api/genre=test&genre=cool`

It shows only `cool` ....

Why multiple value is not obtained??

I want to get the value list like this below

```
genres = list(request.query_params.get("genre"))
```

And it doesn't work as Post.

Does anyone help???

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31085440/6759844) might help

Comment: Use `.getlist()` instead of `.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

I just use `.getlist()` instead of `.get()`

Thank you for the comment by `John Gordon`